# SQL Error [HY000]: XML Parser Error in Search For quickbooks

Tags: sql, quickbooks, cdata, dbeaver

I'm connecting to quickbooks instance via Dbeaver(6.1.5.201908191349). when i try to execute basic query like

> SELECT * FROM CData.QuickBooks.Accounts

I get the below error.

> SQL Error [HY000]: XML Parser Error in Search.

I have no clue what is going wrong here. When i try from java code also i get the same error. Please need some help to solve this issue.

Comment: Given the error message, it doesn't look like the problem is with DBeaver itself, but with QuickBooks. The QBSDK has a bug that is triggered when the returned data contains non-ASCII characters (e.g. umlauts). Try checking your data (such as account names) to make sure you don't have any special characters in there.

Comment: Thanks alot for info. Finally found out that iwas because of wrong driver. Was using qb offline jar instead of  online jar